# ConfirmationMail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email, smtpclient

I am doing Confirmation mail sent to the register following with this URL

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/12/06/email-confirmation-asp-net-mvc-web-application.aspx#comments

but i am getting errors.Can anyone help me.

```
message.Subject = "Please Verify your Account";
MailBody.Append("<html><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' align='center'>" + "<tr><td><p>Dear " + user.UserName+ "</p><br>");
MailBody.Append("To verify your account, please click the following link:<span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a href=verifyUrl + "\" target="http://localhost:51819">" + verifyUrl + "+"</a></span> to complete your registration.<br>);
```

Comment: it is like 1) New line in constant 2) ) expected  3); expected  I tried bt i am not getting

Comment: Just as a suggestion, there is a class dedicated to 'building up' a HTML string, called `HTMLTextWriter`. Will save you having html tags in your string builder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes in your second append.  The script highlighter even shows the error.

If you want double quotes within a string it needs to be escaped, e.g. \"

So your second appending should be something like this

```
  MailBody.Append("To verify your account, please click the following link:<span style='font-weight:bold;'><a href=\"" 
    + verifyUrl + "\" target=\"http://localhost:51819\">" 
    + verifyUrl + "</a></span> to complete your registration.<br>");
```

Comment: @user1915528 - FYI : Questions / comments like "please send me the code" will not go do down well on Stack Overflow - People here are more than happy to help out with guidance but we are not here to write your app / code for you.

Comment: thankq for all and one more i was created database for this but i am getting error like unable to connect to the database....

Comment: that would be a separate question.

Comment: I mean, create this as a separate question entirely on stackoverflow as it is different to the question above

Comment: no probs, you're new here.  it's also expected that you accept an answer if that solved that particular problem, so either myself or balexandre's answer for this question by the looks of it, whichever fixed this problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `New line in constant` is due to the fact you're breaking the line without telling the compiler that you want a second line.

There is 3 ways you can fix this:

- don't break the line
- escape every special character
- use `@` sign to do what you want

As an example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<html><table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' align='center'>");
sb.Append("<tr><td><p>Dear " + user.UserName+ "</p><br>");
sb.Append("To verify your account, please click the following link:<span style='font-weight:bold;'>");
sb.Append("<a href='" + verifyUrl + "' target='http://localhost:51819'>" + verifyUrl + "</a></span> to complete your registration.<br>");

MailBody.Append(sb.ToString());
```

You also need to **avoid using a mix of single and double quotes inside a string**, the idea is to only use **single quotes inside and use double quotes to delimit the string**.

You can also use the `@` in front of a string and **you can then break the line** like this:

```
MailBody.Append(
   String.Format(
     @"<html>
       <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' align='center'>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <p>Dear {0}</p>
             To verify your account, please click the following link:
             <span style='font-weight:bold;'>
               <a href='{1}'>{1}</a>
             </span> to complete your registration.
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       </html>", user.UserName, verifyUrl));
```

I also used `StringBuilder` to avoid having variables inside the template, as it makes it way more simple to see and edit.

And **last, but not least**, you should know a little bit more about HTML ... there is no such thing as `target="http://localhost:51819"`...

Answer (score 0):

Your second `MailBody.Append` is all messed up

```
MailBody.Append("To verify your account, please click the following link:<span style='font-weight:bold;'> <a href="+verifyUrl + "\" target=\"http://localhost:51819\">" + verifyUrl + "</a></span> to complete your registration.<br>");
```